# GAS : upload File using HTML service

Tags: file-upload, google-apps-script

I am in the process of building my first application that makes use of Google Apps Script & HTMLService. I need to have a form that allows the upload of a file to a Google Documents List.
This is my current code and it doesn't work .

index.html :
This page contains a simple form (action="<=? action ?>") with a input file (name & id equal myFile) and submit button

code.gs :

```
function doGet(e) {
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(index.html');
template.action = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
return template.evaluate();
}


function doPost(e) {
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Thanks.html');
var f = DocsList.createFile(e.parameter.myFile);
return template.evaluate();
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't work" and explain what is happening.

Comment: the function DocsList.createFile(e.parameter.myFile)
return this error : Cannot find method createFile(string). how can I do to upload file with HTMLService plz

Answer (score 1):

Files do not show up to doPost this way. Let me think about whether there's a good workaround.

Comment: Corey, were you able to think of anyway to do file upload from HTML-Service? TXS.

Comment: You could always do file uploads from HTML Service (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#GoogleScriptAPI and specifically the part labeled "Forms"). I was thinking about a doPost workaround for a different reason, but it appears I misunderstood the initial question months ago because this has been supported via google.script.run since it launched.

Comment: Corey, I am actually POSTing to my script from an outside source (not using HTML-Service).  I figured it would be the same result, however as you pointed out, HTML-service seems to have some built in magic and does list the file Blobs in the e.parameter.   I entered a ticket [here] (http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2229)  to try to remedy for regular doPost(e)

Answer (score 0):

I just read in documentation DocList.createFile(blob) is only avaliable for Google Apps accounts:

> method createFile(blobSource)
>
> Creates a file with the given name and content in the DocsList. This
>   method is only available for Google Apps accounts.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_docslist?hl=es-ES#createFile

Comment: This message was removed by Nov 22, 2012.  May be now createFile is available for regular accounts.